# Using placeholders in watchdog function

Tags: forms, ajax, log-messages

I know this is simple. I have a callback function `callback` below:

```
function callback($id = '121-01927'){
    watchdog('print', '%message : Sample',array('%message' => $id), WATCHDOG_DEBUG, $link = NULL);
}
```

After executing the callback function, I viewed `watchdog` table in my database, and it says there.

```
%message : Sample
```

It seems my placeholder `%message` is not substituted by the variable `$id`. Where am I missing?

Comment: Looks alright to me, have you tried using `dpm($id)` to make sure the variable is being set correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The placeholders are not supposed to be substituted in the database.

This is because the `watchdog()` function can be called from anywhere, for any user, with any language. 
Mid you call `t()` function, which usually does the placeholder substitutions and translation, that function used the current language to translate to. Now, if you call `watchdog()` to log an error for user A, whose language is `de`, the message should not be saved to the database as the `de`-translated string. That is why the english untranslated strong is stored.

When an administrator views the log (From Admin -> Reports -> Recent log items), Drupal does the translation call (`t()`) at that very moment. All entries will then be translated to the language the current user has configured.